# How do you write an ordered recursive query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

This probably has been asked 1000 times before but I couldn't find it.

I have the following database design:

```
Table Comment
ID     UserID     CommentText    DateTime          ReplyTo
1      19823      Nice site!     2013-07-08 11:14  NULL
2      232912     Sure this is   2013-07-08 11:15  1
3      84291      Can we get     2013-07-08 11:16  NULL
4      300192     I listened to  2013-07-08 11:17  1
```

I would like to show it like this nested in comment and reply:

```
ID
3
1
  2
  4
```

So what I'd like to achieve is order all comments without a ReplyTo by DateTime DESC and then
for each comment show the replies in datetime ascending order.

Is this possible in one SQL query?

I tried this but it went hopelessly wrong

```
SELECT ID, UserID, CommentText, DateTime 
FROM Comment
LEFT JOIN Comment AS reply ON Comment.ID = Reply.ReplyTo
GROUP BY ID, UserID, CommentText, DateTime
HAVING ReplyTo IS NULL
ORDER BY DateTime Desc
```

Should I split this to two queries and do a `UNION`? Or should I change the design of the database?

Comment: What about just using `ORDER BY  ReplyTo , DateTime `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression) - a technique that allows you to descend through a hierarchy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms175972(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx

...several examples at the end of the article

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take advantage of row_number(), in particular the order by clause and do something like this:

```
select ReplyID, DateTime, replyto,
    row_number() over(order by DateTimedesc) AS OrderID
from reply
where replyto is null
union
select ReplyID, DateTime, replyto,
    row_number() over(order by DateTimeasc) AS OrderID
from reply
where replyto is not null
```

Comment: hmmmm, missed the second part of the order by - comments with replyto in ascending order

Comment: shouldn't there be a joing between the ReplyTo and ReplyID so SQL knows which comment replies to which?

Comment: jao, adding a partition by replyto in the second select of the union will result in the data being returned in replyto order first, with replyto's the same comment ordered by datetime

Comment: row_number() over(partition by replyto order by datetime asc)